# Reducing the Expiration time of key provided by InstanceMetaDataService and change Update Frequency

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I created an EC2 Instance with an Instance profile that only has READ access to one bucket. The way I understand is, the secret key and access key will be rotated by amazon and that I won't need to keep any keys inside my application or machine. However I can get that access key, secret key, and authorization by logging into an instance and accessing a URL.
`http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/`, returns the role name and `http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/<role_name>` returns a JSON Text like below.

```
{
"Code" : "Success",
"LastUpdated" : "2014-02-26T06:54:56Z",
"Type" : "AWS-HMAC",
"AccessKeyId" : "SOME_ACCESS_KEY",
"SecretAccessKey" : "SOME_SECRET_KEY",
"Token" :    "A_REALLY_BIG_TEXT",
"Expiration" : "2014-02-26T13:00:45Z"
}
```

Now I can use these to access allowed resources even outside my EC2 Instance, for example using `BasicSessionCredentials` and as I see this one is valid for 6 hours. Is there some way to make it expire say in 15 minutes or some other value like when we create a temporary credentials.

This is updated before it expires, can't tell how often but I have seen it gets updated at around 1 hr interval, can I somehow make change this update frequency as well?

Answer (score 1):

AWS documentation explains and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/DisablingTokenPermissions.html) and [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/TokenPermissions.html) that

> Temporary security credentials are valid until they expire, and they cannot be revoked. However, because policies are evaluated each time an AWS request is made using the temporary security credentials, you can modify access rights for temporary credentials after the credentials have been issued.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I get that once they are issued they cannot be revoked and that I can change the permissions even after they have been issued so any subsequent request will be affected. What I am interested is - Can I change how often the credentials are changed and how quickly it expires? I know if I create a temporary credential for a role then I can set it to expire from 15 minutes upwards. Is there something similar for machines launched with `IamInstanceProfile` ?

Comment: You can't influence the time *temporary credentials* expire. You could [disable temporary credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/UsingSTS/DisablingTokenPermissions.html) and work with [IAM roles](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/06/iam-roles-for-ec2-instances-simplified-secure-access-to-aws-service-apis-from-ec2.html) that you [rotate yourself](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/Using_RotatingCredentials.html).